# Configure an Apache Camel route between two ActiveMQ queues to use a producer for the specific destination queue rather than an unidentified producer

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm trying to configure Apache Camel with ActiveMQ to bridge between a queue on *my* ActiveMQ server and a queue on a *remote* ActiveMQ server. So far so simple. Here is the relevant bit of my `camel.xml`:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="camel">
  <route>
    <from uri="local:Request"/>
    <to uri="remote:Request"/>
  </route>
</camelContext>

<bean id="local" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
  <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
</bean>

<bean id="remote" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
  <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://remote:61616"/>
</bean>
```

I've tested this on two servers I control, and it works fine. However, the remote server I'm trying to connect to is one I *don't* control, and (probably due to a badly-written bespoke authorization implementation) it is exhibiting a behaviour that doesn't seem to work nicely with Camel.

The issue is this: the remote server relies on all `Producer` instances that connect to it being **for a specified destination**, whereas by default, Camel seems to create an **unidentified** producer ([JMS reference for context](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnceo/index.html)). If an unidentified producer is created, this remote server simply terminates the connection.

So the question I have is this: is there a way to force Camel to *not* use an **unidentified** producer, preferably without having to modify the Camel source code?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe about specified destinations sounds like the default endpoint of [ProducerTemplate](http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html). I have no idea if this really creates the producer as you like, but you could give it a try.

Create a Java bean that uses a ProducerTemplate to send the messages to the remote broker. Create the [ProducerTemplate with a default endpoint](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/impl/DefaultProducerTemplate.html#DefaultProducerTemplate(org.apache.camel.CamelContext,%20org.apache.camel.Endpoint)) so that you don't need to specify the endpoint to send messages.

Then change your route to use the bean as sender

```
.to("bean:mySenderBean")
```